# How to create a dialog using JFXDialog of JFoenix in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

i search for an example for **jfoenix jfxdialog** anybody has working demo of this

```
JFXDialog dialog = new JFXDialog();
```

Answer (score 12):

`JFXDialog` has three different constructors:

1. `JFXDialog()`,
2. `JFXDialog(StackPane dialogContainer, Region content, DialogTransition transitionType)` and
3. `JFXDialog(StackPane dialogContainer, Region content, DialogTransition transitionType, boolean overlayClose)`

The first one just sets the `animationType` to `Center`.

The second one sets the Parent(`dialogContainer`), the content(`content`) and the animationType(`transitionType`).

The third one sets the same as the second one + if the dialog should close if you click on the overlay(`overlayClose`).

For the parent of the Dialog you need a `StackPane`.

For the content you can use anything which is a child, grandchild, ... of `Region`. I would suggest you to use a `JFXDialogLayout` as it extends `StackPane` and makes it easier to style you dialog.

For the `transitionType` you have five different ones:

- `DialogTransition.TOP`
- `DialogTransition.RIGHT`
- `DialogTransition.BOTTOM`
- `DialogTransition.LEFT`
- `DialogTransition.CENTER`

If you want to close it by clicking on the overlay set `overlayClose` to `true`, else set it to `false`

Some usefull methods which `JFXDialog` has:

- `setDialogContainer(StackPane dialogContainer)` sets the Parent.
- `setContent(Region content)` sets the Content of your Dialog.
- `setOverlayClose(final boolean overlayClose)` you set wheter you want to close the Dialog by clicking on the overlay or not.
- `show(StackPane dialogContainer)` shows the `JFXDialog` in the given `StackPane`
- `show()` shows the `JFXDialog` in its parent
- `close()` closes the `JFXDialog`
- `setTransitionType(DialogTransition transition)` sets the `DialogTransition` to one of those mentioned before
- `setOnDialogClosed(EventHandler<? super JFXDialogEvent> handler)` Defines a function to be called when the dialog is closed. It will be triggered after the close animation is finished.
- `setOnDialogOpened(EventHandler<? super JFXDialogEvent> handler)` Defines a function to be called when the dialog is opened. It will be triggered after the show animation is finished.

---

`JFXDialogLayout` has just an empty constructor but contains out of a `heading`, `body` and `actions`.

The `JFXDialogLayout` class provides a setter for all those parts. Those are:

- `setHeading(Node... titleContent`
- `setBody(Node... body)`
- `setActions(Node... actions)`

If you don't know, because of the three dots after `Node` you can add unlimited Nodes to  all three parts. This is a feature called [Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

---

For further information take a look at the demo on github at the Java controller [JFoenix/Dialog Container](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/master/demo/demos/gui/uicomponents/DialogController.java) and at the FXML file [JFoenix/JFXDialog.fxml](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/master/demo/resources/fxml/ui/Dialog.fxml)

Also here is the source code of the controls containing `JFXDialog` and `JFXDialogLayout` [JFoenix/controls](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/master/src/com/jfoenix/controls)

I would suggest you to write your JavaFX applications seperated in Java, FXML and CSS files. [Why Use FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/why_use_fxml.htm)